# Prove that the extremity of the polar subtangent of the curve $u+f(\theta)=0$ is $u=f'(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2})$ where $u=\frac{1}{r}$

Tags: calculus, curves, locus, tangent-line

Prove that the extremity of the polar subtangent of the curve

$$u+f(\theta)=0$$  is $$u=f^{\prime} \left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2} \right)$$ where $u=\frac{1}{r}$

I am confused and I think that it should be $$u=f^{\prime} \left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2} \right)$$

Please Help me out !

Answer (score 0):

Diagram is given in this link(fig2.7). Sorry I couldn't upload the image as it's not uploading at all!

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://nitkkr.ac.in/docs/2-Geometrical%2520Applications%2520of%2520Differentiation.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj4ncTQi_vdAhXMbisKHZJZCCMQFjACegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw1ztz84IEZqUmGOihWjNwka

Let the coordinates of the extremity of the polar subtangent be T(r, θ1).

Now, given f(θ)=-u.

Differentiate both sides
                    du/dθ = -f'(θ).

So polar subtangent is given by

r1= - dθ/du= -1/(-f'(θ))=1/f'(θ)   [1]

The angle made by the polar subtangent with the initial line is

θ1=π/2 -θ or

θ=θ1+ π/2.

Now putting the value of θ in [1] we get 
 r1=1/f'(θ1 + π/2)

Hence the locus is

r=1/f'(θ+π/2)   [Generalising it for all possible values of θ and r]

Putting u=1/r we get

u=f'(θ+π/2)